# Navigation in JavaFX tableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have the following code which generates a `TableView`,

```
public class NavExample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Z", "X"), new Person("A", "B"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        table.getFocusModel().focus(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

I am selecting the first row by default using,

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Once the **Application** is launched,

Navigation (UP and DOWN keys) doesn't work until i select inside the `table`.(though i keep focus `table.getFocusModel().focus(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());`)

Also , If a row is selected(By holding shift) on clicking "Down or UP", row selection doesn't get retained instead next row's cells 
are getting selected.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to request a focus on the table itself, not a specific row/cell:

```
table.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the focus issue. Is it possible to retain row selection while navigating?(now row selection is not retained)

Comment: @user3164187 You cannot, because you enabled cell selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you use cell selection mode, you need to focus a cell not a row, so you need to specify a `TableColumn` to focus:

```
// table.getFocusModel().focus(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
table.getFocusModel().focus(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), table.getColumns().get(0));
```